# Changing gtksourceview files adding a style

Tags: themes, markdown, gedit, gtksourceview

I want to change the way list markers of markdown files are displayed in `GEdit` in the theme `tomorrow_night-eighties.xml`, which I downloaded from https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes. I know that GEdit loads its language specs from

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```

The markdown language file is `markdown.lang`. The styles are located in my users directory:

```
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles
```

What I did is the following:

1. I added: `<style name="markdown:list-marker" foreground="#cc99cc" bold="true"/>` to the list of available styles in the style document.in my user's `.local/share/....` folder.
2. I changed in the language specs:

   `<style id="list-marker" _name="List Marker" map-to="markdown:list-marker"/>`
   in the `<styles>...</styles>` region / tag, in order to make it available for referencing further down.

My theme is set to the `tomorrow_night-eighties.xml` one I have in my `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles` and a markdown file is opened. After the change GEdit doesn't highlight list markers at all anymore.

What I don't understand is, what is missing? I only changed a reference and introduced a new style and didn't change the regex at all, so why does that stop it from highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems GEdit does not automatically notice changes in those files and one has to re-import the styles in the preferences and just to be sure also restart GEdit if the language file changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with identifiers for `<context>` and `<language>` tags when creating an `id=` attribute, perhaps also for the `<style>` tag.

see [also in stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668247/why-are-identifiers-for-the-id-attribute-of-gtksourcview-language-and-context-ta)

The prototypical test suite below was run in this environment:

```
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ gedit  -V
gedit - Version 3.28.1

linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:00 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

The test suite language file that demonstrates this failure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 This file is part of GtkSourceView
 special mods for extended background highlighting and comments MJS aka etx 2021

id (mandatory)
Identifier for the description. 
This is used for external references and must be unique among language descriptions. 
It can contain a string of letters, digits, hyphens ("-") and underscores ("_"). NOT!!!

as follows for   id    attribute of both tags     language   &   context

empirical evidence gathered via simultaneously changing both id's to be identical

fails  reliably:    xRef
fail unreliably:    x-ref   X_-ef3
    but     aOk:    xref  xref3   x-ref3
-->
<language id="xRef"   name="C..C xref augment cpp"   version="2.0" _section="other">

  <definitions>     
    <context id="special-multiline-comment" style-ref="def:note" >   <!-- hi-liter -->
      <start>/(\*  ..  ..  ..  \*)+/</start>
      <end>\%{0@start}</end>
    </context>

    <!--Main context-->
    <context  class="no-spell-check"   id="xRef" >
      <include>

        <context ref="special-multiline-comment"/>    <!--  override MUST precede to supercede  -->

        <!-- actual language definition: editing hi lite stuff plus everything from C++ -->
        <context ref="cpp:cpp"/>

      </include>
    </context>
  </definitions>
</language>
```